# How can I switch the interface language of Netbeans on Mac OS X?

Tags: netbeans

How can I switch the interface language of netbeans (my version is 6.9.1) on Mac OS X? I would like to use English.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding

```
--locale en_US
```

Instead of

```
--locale en:US
```

As described in the [manual](http://blogs.oracle.com/tao/entry/set_netbeans_user_interface_language)

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X:

1. In the Finder, Ctrl-click `/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans`
2. Choose *Show Package Contents*
3. Browse to `/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf`
4. Edit netbeans.conf
5. Add `-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US` in row
   `netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"`

   It has to be something like this - 
   `useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"`
6. Save
7. Restart netbeans

Comment: This works like a charm on Mac OS 10.14.6 and NetBeans 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

try this: [set_netbeans_user_interface_language](http://blogs.oracle.com/tao/entry/set_netbeans_user_interface_language)

Comment: Strange... I added the line in the end in config then i reloaded netbeans. Language didn't chahge.

Comment: @ExR: try it again. Note that there is double - in argument not single.